# SwiftUI Custom Navigation Bar VStack doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I'm trying to make a custom navigation bar with back button, image, VStack (2 labels) but it didn't work. The whole view will stick to the center and not following the alignment I set. Thank you!

```
struct WeatherNavigation: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            WeatherNavigation()
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

//

```
struct WeatherNavigation: View {
    var body: some View {
                Button(action: {
                    //action
                }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image("Back")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        Image("Weather")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                   }
                })
                .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
            VStack {
                Text(weather.description)
                    .font(.appFont(size: 18))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .black))
                Text(weather.location)
                    .font(.appFont(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .blue))
            }
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 50, alignment: .leading)            
        }
}
```

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, you’re trying to align your items within the VStack to leading? If that is the case, you should understand that .frame targets the VStack and not the items within it. Your code will place the VStack within the frame with .leading, and not the items within it. To achieve alignment within the VStack, try `VStack(alignment: .leading)`.

Comment: I tried VStack(alignment: .leading) too. It only align the labels inside the VStack to leading. I want the whole WeatherNavigation to align to leading (button, image, VStack). But they just all stay in the center of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't set frame of the whole view like that. For you problem, it can divide into: make a `HStack` to store all the container view and make a space between those two of them. Because using HStack you don't need to add leading.

Code will be like this

```swift
struct WeatherNavigation: View {
    var body: some View {
        // make a HStack to store all the attribute
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Button(action: {
                //action
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image("Back")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Image("Weather")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
               }
            })
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            VStack {
                Text("Tokyo")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .black))
                Text("Japan")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .blue))
            }
            // make a space at the end
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage like this

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                WeatherNavigation()
            }
            Spacer()
        }

    }
}
```

**More over**: adding `Spacer()` means that make space between view. That will solved your problem if you want to keep like your way.

Comment: it works for the back and weather image but not with the VStack. VStack is all the way to the right and the HStack is on the left. I set the Spacer() size to 12 didn't help.

Comment: Dear @14079_Z, don't set size to ``Spacer()``. You just need to transfer ``Spacer()`` to the end. Check update code above.